# Two factor authentication turned on for my Google account (Phone) - but still hacked

Tags: multi-factor, google

I just got a message today that someone changed my password on my Google account.

The email seems legit, and Google confirmed there was a login from Ukraine two weeks ago in recent activity.

The password change that happened today occurred in a city in the country I live (Netherlands).

I have two factor authentication turned on - how is this even possible?

This is the view in Google "Your Devices" of the device that changed my password:

[image]

Comment: What type of two factor authentication do you have turned on? There are multiple types. Does the recent activity show any clues what type of 2FA the attacker used? SMS, Google Authenticator, backup code? My first thought was a compromised phone (malicious app installed, rooted phone, etc.) but it depends on which method you used.

Comment: Are you a person of interest for foreign nations? (For example a NATO subcontractor)

Comment: Hi @MartinFürholz, thanks for your msg. I have enabled SMS. Within Google "your devices" I don't see any info about which 2FA they would have used - I've attached a screenshot.

Comment: Hi @A.Hersean, thanks for your message. No, I'm not :)

Comment: Is it possible that you have granted access to a new app, web, add-on, or other soft that requested Google access?

Comment: Hi @jDSL, that for sure. I quite often use SSO to limit the amount of logins/password I scatter over the internet. I was hoping that would be a good thing though :)

Comment: (1) When using SSO, you must ensure that you are filling your authentication data into a Google interface that cannot be intercepted (by the website or app), otherwise you are just giving your access away. Instead of SSO, you should try a password manager. SSO, as it is most often implemented, is an anti-pattern from a security point-of-view. (2) SMS can be intercepted (with a nearby antenna) or redirected (by social engineering your mobile provider or by abusing the SS7 protocol). (2) is less likely than (1) because you are not a person of interest, but not impossible in theory.

Comment: A social engineering approach runs along this line: You receive a call from "_Google Security_" saying that there has been questionable activity _or something_ . For security purposes they need you to verify your identity by reading back the single use PIN they are sending to your phone of record. Now the attacker tries to log into your account and sure enough you receive a PIN from **Google**. You read the PIN back to "_Google Security_", they thank you and you've just given them your 2nd Factor.

Comment: They have malware on your laptop and stole cookies directly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a malware which is spreading nowadays that clone the ID of chrome, so an attacker can access any site/s thanks to cookie sessions saved on that chrome. The technique is very sophisticated and 2FA it's useless here because they're already logged in with your cloned browser id and nothing require to be checked. So most probably, if you're a google chrome user, you could have been affected by this kind of attack. If this is your case, the solution will be as follow:

> ·LogOut your google account from the infected machine (of course, run
>   Malwarebytes or any other kink of anti-malware to delete the virus)
>
> ·Uninstall google chrome and/or any kind of chromium-based browser(and
>   all of its related data)
>
> ·Now you need to change the name of your computer (so the new session
>   will have a different name avoiding name hijacking
>   https://kb.iu.edu/d/ajnx)
>
> ·From a different device change the password of your google account
>
> ·In 2FA google settings revoke all authorized devices
>
> ·Reboot your pc and reinstall chrome.

You should be done.

Comment: any references to this malware? I can find nothing online that does what you have outlined

Comment: AZORult and its related children

Comment: I'm still not seeing any reference to this 2FA-defeating behavior from AZORult

Comment: In fact, there isn't. Many users have been affected by this malware (or similar ones) and they're are reporting they're experiences. It seems very strange that it is able to bypass 2FA and it is still not clear to me how it exactly works. It just copy the chrome ID so the attacker seems an authorized victim and does not require 2FA (in fact, on trusted devices 2FA it's not required, or at least it is not required on google). Anyway this virustotal scan is one of the most recent of the virus: https://www.shorturl.at/shortener.php

Comment: Thanks for your answer! Would it have been possible to simply steal the Google auth cookie? I.e. through a Chrome plugin?

Comment: @DirkBoer Yes, also chrome extensions can steal personal Info and sensitive data of course. The majority of them use CVE to reach their goal.

Comment: wouldn't any change to account preferences (password, 2FA settings, logging in from a new device, etc...) require 2FA again?  I'm wondering if the victim here had chosen not to use 2-Step Verification again on that particular computer and whether that would still allow account changes without 2FA...

Comment: @pcalkins as I said before, even if you have 2FA enabled it isn't asked every time you log in with a trusted device. This is due to cookies and the affordable ID of chrome... Once these elements got stolen and your chrome is cloned, there is no reason to ask for 2FA and btw server cannot distinguish from a legitim client or a corrupted one. Most probably, this bug is due to a CVE discovered in early 2019 in chromium-based browsers.

Comment: right, but seems like for account changes like a password change, you'd want to 2FA again, no?

Comment: @pcalkins on trusted devices it isn't asked anyway I think, you should at least revoke all authorization. But for security, it's better to follow all the steps shown above.

Answer (score 1):

Run forensics on the phone:

- Check the latest app permissions (timeframe of hack happened)
- Get a list of the SMS from OTP provider (from carrier company) (timeframe of hack) compare it to to SMS that you have on the phone (malware could have deleted that)
- Capture packets sent from phone through the wi-fi (deploy a VM, deploy a gateway on it, deploy a wireshark or burpsuite), analyze data, lookup for the connections to WAN IPs it's trying to do.
- Try to get info on that IPs and then think what to do with all that info.